# VS Code intellisense in the way

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

[image: VS Code Intellisense]

I find the suggestions useful, but good-lord I can't see what I'm doing.  I can't find a setting to move the suggestions out of the way.

Comment: What language is it? Have you installed a third-party extension for it?

Comment: is this about the suggests widget or the parameter hints widget, or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, users cannot currently change the position of the Intellisense info popup.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33752) for this but it hasn't received attention in a while.

Comment: 2 years later.. They still haven't fixed it. WoW

Comment: 6 years later...